# How come default exports are listed as having multiple branches by `istanbul` code coverage?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, istanbul

I use [babel-istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-istanbul) to measure test coverage of by ES2016 code. This works relatively well, except that it says my branch coverage is lower than it is. The reason for this appears to be that it is interpretting the default export differently than I am:

[image: Screenshot of my code coverage]

As can be seen, it marks my default export with an `E` saying "else path not taken". As far as I understand it, there is just one path here. What am I doing wrong?

(And if you're really dedicated: the code can be found [at GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Vinnl/makeapoint/tree/master).)

**Edit:** It turns out this only happens when I use Babel 6.7.5 and above, so I reported [a bug](https://github.com/jmcriffey/babel-istanbul/issues/63).

Comment: You should put your edit in as an answer :)

Comment: It doesn't really solve the problem, but I guess it's somewhat of an answer... I'll add it, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The author of `babel-istanbul` [helped tremendously](https://github.com/jmcriffey/babel-istanbul/issues/63) to pinpoint this issue arising in Babel 6.7.5 - it did work with version 6.7.4.

I never got it to work with later versions, but replacing it with isparta proved sufficient for me.